# simulate first time visiting the web page?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a bug that only happens on first visit to the website which is regarding animation flickering.

After first visit, the bug somehow disappears

I tried

- clear cache and browser history
- incognito mode
- disable cache

none can simulate the first visit right after deployment, which makes debugging very difficult

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you

Comment: Are you waiting until everything is loaded?

Comment: yes, the website wait unit the image loaded, if loaded, then the page becomes visible and fire animation

Comment: I think we need to see your code and preferably a snippet which we can run.

Comment: I think I found the problem
I set "visibility = none" in css
then I set "visibility = visible" with js when image is loaded
should use display instead of visiblity because animation still firest when visiblity is none